# iText7 Knowing if a table has extended in more pages

Tags: c#, itext7

is possible in itext7 knowing if a table (added to document) occupies 1 or more pages and in which page has placed ?

I've tried in an Handler on END_PAGE:

```
 IRenderer pRenderer = TableData.CreateRendererSubTree().SetParent(doc.GetRenderer());
 LayoutResult pLayoutResult = pRenderer.Layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, PageSize.A4)));

float y = pLayoutResult.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetY();
float x = pLayoutResult.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetX();
float xBottom = pLayoutResult.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetBottom();
float xHeight = pLayoutResult.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetHeight();
int pageNumber= pLayoutResult.GetOccupiedArea().GetPageNumber();
```

I've tried with table only on first page and with table extended on first and second page.

pageNumber is always = 0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible. iText 7 allows you to override rendering logic, one of the simplest applications of which is knowing where on the page your elements are going to be placed.

As a helper means to store the information about pages on which our table is placed, we can define a small class:

```
private static class LayoutInfo {
    Collection<Integer> occupiedPages = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPage(int pageNum) {
        occupiedPages.add(pageNum);
    }

    public Collection<Integer> getOccupiedPages() {
        return occupiedPages;
    }
}
```

Now, we can define our custom table renderer which is going to store the page numbers into this `LayoutInfo` object:

```
private static class CustomTableRenderer extends TableRenderer {
    private LayoutInfo layoutInfo;

    public CustomTableRenderer(Table modelElement, LayoutInfo info) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.layoutInfo = info;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.draw(drawContext);
        layoutInfo.addPage(occupiedArea.getPageNumber());
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomTableRenderer((Table) modelElement, layoutInfo);
    }
}
```

You have to set the custom renderer to the table after all the cells have been added into it and the table is ready to be added to the document:

```
table.setNextRenderer(new CustomTableRenderer(table, info));
```

Full high level code:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));

Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

LayoutInfo info = new LayoutInfo();

Table table = new Table(2);
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    table.addCell("Row number ");
    table.addCell(i + "");
}
table.setNextRenderer(new CustomTableRenderer(table, info));
document.add(table);

document.close();

System.out.println("The table is placed on the following pages: " + info.getOccupiedPages().toString());
```

Output of the code:

```
The table is placed on the following pages: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that the code is in Java but translating into C# is mostly a matter of changing cases of characters in a couple of places.